# how do I make my if, else code work? I'm stumped

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm stumped using if else statements. Should I be using something else for this particular code?
I'm trying to get it to break the loop but its stuck in the larger loop...

```
package Base;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.println("Unscrammble the          state capitols:\n");       
        System.out.println("NNLSIGA");

        String Answer = input.nextLine();

        if("Lansing".equals(Answer));
        else {
            System.out.println("Hint: Capitol of the     Great Lake State");
            Answer = input.nextLine();

            if("Lansing".equals(Answer));
            else System.out.println("Try again");

            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("INNOAPASL");

        Answer = input.nextLine();

        // next question
```

Comment: `if("Lansing".equals(Answer));` Do you wish to do something when the condition is met (in other words, lose the semicolon)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolon after `if("Lansing".equals(Answer));`.Semicolon after `if();` makes the if statement completed  means the statements after `if` is not a part of `if` like you can say your `if` condition is like `if("Lansing".equals(Answer)){}` ie nothing to execute when its true, this is because of the semicolon .Semicolon after if will also give you error(else without if error) for `else` part.

And also if you are not executing anything in `if(true)` but you are only excuting in `if(false)` (you can also say else part of `if(true)` like your case) you can simply change condition to
 `if(!("Lansing".equals(Answer)))` ie adding a `!` operator so `if(!true)` same as `if(false)` which would be helpful in your case

Comment: Thanks mate! :) Aware this is a dumb beginner question I was just tired of trying to figure it out and knowing something was way off.

Answer (score 1):

I see no loops here but you should remove the ; after the if statements, as it makes the if statements empty :

```
if("Lansing".equals(Answer));
                            ^
```

If you only have logic for the else case, just negate the condition :

```
String Answer = input.nextLine();

if(!"Lansing".equals(Answer)) {
    System.out.println("Hint: Capitol of the     Great Lake State");
    Answer = input.nextLine();
}

if(!"Lansing".equals(Answer))
     System.exit(0);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the if block wrong.

The correct syntax for an if statement is

```
if(condition) {
// your code
}
```

if you write `if(condition);` it ll skip the block